# Normal Covariance Estimation

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, multilevel-analysis

I have a hierarchical model and I'm struggling to develop an estimator of the covariance of a normal distribution. This is my specific problem. There are $n$ latent $p$-dimensional vectors,
$$\boldsymbol{X}_1,...,\boldsymbol{X}_n \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(\boldsymbol{\mu}_0,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0)$$
where both $\boldsymbol{\mu}_0$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0$ are unknown. Once these values are fixed, I then observe
$$\boldsymbol{Y}_i|\boldsymbol{X}_i \sim N(\boldsymbol{X}_i,c_if(\boldsymbol{X}_i))$$
for $i=1,\ldots,n$. The constant, $c_i$, is known and $f$ is given by
$$f(\boldsymbol{X}_i)=\boldsymbol{A}^\top(\boldsymbol{D}_i-\boldsymbol{1}_{(p+1)\times (p+1)})\boldsymbol{A}$$
where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is known $(p+1)\times p$ matrix (and independent of $i$). Also, $\boldsymbol{D}_i=\text{diag}(1/Z_{i,1},\ldots,1/Z_{i,p+1})$ where $Z_{i,j}=\dfrac {\exp(\boldsymbol{A}_j\boldsymbol{X}_i)} {\sum_{k=1}^p \exp(\boldsymbol{A}_k \boldsymbol{X}_i)}$ and $\boldsymbol{A}_j$ denotes the $j$th row of $\boldsymbol{A}$.

Since the conditional distribution of $\boldsymbol{Y}_i$ depends on $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ in an odd way, the marginal distribution of $\boldsymbol{Y}_i$ is not normal. This poses a particular challenge. What are the best options for estimating $\boldsymbol{\mu}_0$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0$? I have a crude approach for estimating both parameters by essentially replacing $f(\boldsymbol{X}_i)$ with $f(\boldsymbol{\bar X})$. But is there a good computational approach for estimating MLEs in this situation? Or is there some analytical solution I've overlooked?

Comment: What guarantees that $f(\boldsymbol{X}_i)$ is positive semidefinite, and therefore a valid covariance matrix?

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to revisit this. I originally misspecified $D_i$ but have since corrected it. The fact that $f(\boldsymbol{X}_i)$ is psd follows from the fact that $u^\top (D_i - 1_{(p+1)\times (p+1)}) u= \sum_{j=1}^{p+1}u_j^2 \dfrac 1 {Z_{i,j}} - (\sum_{j=1}^{p+1}u_j)^2$. Since $0 \le Z_{i,j} \le 1$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality guarantees this is positive.

Comment: Kind of messy and computationally intensive, bu if nothing better comes along: Form likelihood by numerical integration, and maximize it using numerical nonlinear optimization, using your crude approach to provide starting values for the nonlinear optimization. This may be a kind of ugly nonlinear SDP (semidefinite programming problem), due to the need for a semidefinite constraint for $\Sigma_0$.  Either use a nonlinear SDP solver, or a "standard" solver using a Cholesky factor parameterization for $\Sigma_0$, which will enforce psd, but possibly at expense of introducing saddlepoints.$.

Comment: Good suggestion. The increased computational cost as $p$ grows is a bit of a mystery to me. If you were approaching this problem, at what value of $p$ would you throw in the towel and content yourself with a crude approach? (Assuming you don't plan to throw huge computational resources at the problem.)